# Change date format - bash or php

Tags: bash, date, timestamp

I have been gathering data for the last 20 days using a bash script that runs every 5 minutes. I started the script with no idea how I was going to output the data. I have since found a rather cool js graph that reads from a CSV.

Only issue is my date is currently in the format of:

Fri Nov 6 07:52:02

and for the CSV I need it to be

2015-11-06 07:52:02

So I need to cat my results grep-ing for the date and convert it.

The cat/grep for the date is:

```
cat speeds.txt | grep 2015 | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4}'
```

Any brainwaves on how I can switch this around either using bash or php?

Thanks

PS - Starting the checks again using date +%Y%m%d" "%H:%M:%S is sadly not an option :(

Comment: Can you post two lines of sample data? Also, your `grep` has 2015 in it but your date doesn't.

Comment: The grep for 2015 is just because that is the unique object on the line, grepping for anything else could get false-positives.  


Fri Nov 6 09:09:18  
Fri Nov 6 09:14:46  


is 2 lines of output from the cat/grep. Or did you want without the grepping?

Comment: I was just saying in the date you have in your text file: `Fri Nov 6 07:52:02` there is no 2015, so grepping for 2015 won't give you anything. I'm guessing it was a copy-paste error. If you update your question with a sample line I can update my answer below to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all of your lines contains dates:

```
$ cat file        
Fri Nov 6 07:52:02
...
$ awk 'BEGIN {
  months["Jan"] = 1;
  months["Feb"] = 2;
  months["Mar"] = 3;
  months["Apr"] = 4;
  months["May"] = 5;
  months["Jun"] = 6;
  months["Jul"] = 7;
  months["Aug"] = 8;
  months["Sep"] = 9;
  months["Oct"] = 10;
  months["Nov"] = 11;
  months["Dec"] = 12;
}
{
  month = months[$2];
  printf("%s-%02d-%02d %s\n", 2015, month, $3, $4);
}' file > out
$ cat out
2015-11-06 07:52:02
...
```

If you only need to modify a some of the lines you can tweak the awk script a little bit, eg. match every line containing `2015`:

```
...
# Match every line containing 2015
/2015/ {
  month = months[$2];
  printf("%s-%02d-%02d %s\n", 2015, month, $3, $4);
  # Use next to prevent this the other print to happen for these lines 
  #   Like 'continue' in while iterations
  next;
};
# This '1' will print all other lines as well:
#   Same as writing { print $0 }
1
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks, this worked perfectly - put the output of my grep into a new text file then ran this script on it and job done.

Comment: @user1972018 I just updated with a little more info that might suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date format to epoch time format in bash script.

```
date -d 'Fri Nov 6 07:52:02' +%s;

1446776522

date -d @1446776522 +"%Y-%m-%d %T "

2015-11-06 07:52:02
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide the input, I'll assume you have a file called `speeds.txt` that contains:

```
Fri Oct 31 07:52:02  3
Fri Nov 1 08:12:04  4
Fri Nov 2 07:43:22  5
```

(the `3`, `4`, and `5` above are just to show that you could have other data in the row, but are not necessary).

Using this command:

```
cat speeds.txt | cut -d ' ' -f2,3,4 | while read line ; do date -d"$line" "+2015-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" ; done;
```

You get the output:

```
2015-10-31 07:52:02
2015-11-01 08:12:04
2015-11-02 07:43:22
```